# TestFlight: New version of existing app

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect, testflight

I need to create a new version of my app. Can I use testflight to distribute for testing the new version of my app?

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can . Just submit your build with new version no via xcode organizer or application loader. Your new build will be available for internal testing in itunesconnect after processing. And after you done with beta testing review it will be available for external testing .